# Serialization serialversionuid in java

Tags: java

I just want to know why we take only long type serialVersionUID variable in java

```
`public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;`
```

I mean i know how it works + what is serialization etc.

But i am just curious to know that why we only take long primitive type ? why not int or any other type?

like this

```
 public static final int serialVersionUID = 1;
```

Is java specification tell us to do that?

Comment: pls read my question carefully :)

Comment: This question is a total duplicate IMO, but I will add here that by using `long` the Java specification makes collisions between objects that much less likely than using a smaller type such as `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from the docs of [java.io.Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

> A serializable class can declare its own serialVersionUID explicitly
>   by declaring a field named "serialVersionUID" that **must** be static,
>   final, **and of type long**.

So yes the specification tells us to use long. Otherwise it won't be recognized as the serialVersionUID.

Comment: thanks for replying but any reason why long type ?
As @Tim commented above bcoz of less collision between objects

Comment: I don't have a source for that but i think its just that long is "longer" and as such can have much more different value than int. I think they chose it to be sure to make the serialVersionUID as distinct as possible. SO with an int if you had more than (2^32)-1 diffrent revisions of your class you'd have a problem.